# Reference-counted object is used after it is release? NSXMLParser

Tags: xml, xcode, memory, nsxmlparser, memory-leaks

I've download this code from this website. http://homepages.ius.edu/rwisman/C490/html/nsxmlparser.htm

As I analyze it. I have memory leaks. I've tried google everything from autorelease, sender, nil ,[parser setDelegate: [Top10Parser new]], etc. it doesn't work.

I NEED HELP.

```
- (void) run: (id) param  {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    NSXMLParser *parser = [NSXMLParser alloc];
    [parser initWithContentsOfURL: url];
```

[parser setDelegate: self]; <- ("Reference-counted object is used after it is release")

```
    [parser parse];
    [parser release];

    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(parseDidComplete:)])
        [delegate performSelector:@selector(parseDidComplete:) onThread: thread 
                       withObject: outstring waitUntilDone:NO];

    [pool release];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change these two lines:

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [NSXMLParser alloc];
[parser initWithContentsOfURL: url];
```

to

```
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: url];
```

To some schools of thought, `+alloc` returns an owned object and init methods neither add nor remove ownership. It is more correct -- and it is how the analyzer treats it -- to think of an init method consuming a reference on the receiver and returning an owned object. So, if you call an init method but don't assign the result to `self`, then the ownership you had for `self` has been consumed and you have no pointer to the new owned object. All future uses of `self` are using an object you no longer own.